# "Any tool to generate Web Service Proxy for .Net 1.1"

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, .net-1.1, webservice-client

I've a WSDL file with links to external XSD's (I've the xsd's as well deployed to the correct relative path as it's reference in WSDL). When I'm trying to generate a proxy with VS 2003 (.Net 1.1 wsdl tool) The proxy didn't get generated. However it worked fine for VS 2005. What could be wrong. Any idea?

It gives Unable to Import Binding and didn't generates a proxy class.

PS: My wsdl file is very long and there are dozens of xsd it referenced so can't post all here.

### EDIT:

Is there any other tool available which can generate the proxy for .Net 1.1 (preferably CSharp).

Comment: Look at the complete message. It tells you exactly why it couldn't generate the proxy. Also, .NET 2.0 had several bug fixes in this area. It's possible that you're seeing a bug which has already been fixed in .NET 2.0.

Comment: I understand this but I need to work on the 2003 proxy because of a dependency related to MS Dynamics CRM 3.0 callouts and workflows.

Comment: Reasons to upgrade #1: sometimes bugs get fixed in later releases - and not in the earlier ones.

Comment: v1.1 is nearly 10 years old. I'd really, really consider upgrading.

Comment: Really. It's only going to get worse, not better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were spaces in some attribute names in the XSD which were causing the proxy not to generate. I removed the spaces and modified some XSD's by hand to generate a some what partially correct proxy. I ended up updating the generated proxies by hand to remove the errors.